# Argument to choose the plot to be shown

Tags: python, numpy, argparse

I have 2 plot it's work using my data analysis. I have some options `-x`, `-y`, `-e` — these work.
Now I am trying to add to arguments:

```
--first 
--second
```

When we execute the `file.py --first`, it should show the first plot and exit; if we choose `--second`, the second plot and exit.  I am trying to solve that but I could not find the solution.

```
def Plot_XvsY(x,y):
    plot(x1,y1,'bx-',ms=5)
    plot(x2,y2,'r+-',ms=3)
    show()


def plot_wVSs(w,s):
    plot(w,s,'bx-',ms=5)
    plot(w,s,'r+-',ms=3)
    show()


parser.add_argument('-c', '--first', action='store_true', default=False)
```

**Note:** it's just part of the code to give you an idea  about the issue.

And what if i want to :

> for exemple if i have x.py and y.py and arg_argument.py and when i put ./x.py -h or ./y.py -h they have the same argument , i want to use some argument in x ONLY and the others on Y ONLY and mybe some arguments in X AND Y

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: i have 4 files Plot.py da.py(data) and GUI.py for args and View.py so when i do test in the Gui of args if(first): plotname function .. quit() it not work

Comment: could you post the code you tried to use that did not work and either the traceback message it raised or what it did differently from what you expected it to do?

Comment: it's a huge code ...

Comment: juste i want to know how can i done that function

Comment: What are `if(first)` and `quit()`? Please post them!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out [mcve]. If your actual code is too big, try to make a simple mock-up that is only big enough to show the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

A parser along this line should behave as you describe. (this is just a sketch, and not tested).

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
....
parser.add_argument('--first', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--second', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.first:
    <<call the plt1 function>>
elif args.second:
    <<call the other>>
else:
    <<do something else>>
```

[plugins pattern + sub command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36986250/901925)
Includes module import xtatements

Comment: But the module for function is not the module whit Arguments ? how can i reslove that

Comment: for exemple if i have x.py and y.py and arg_argument.py and when i put ./x.py -h or ./y.py -h they have the same argument , i want to use some argument in x ONLY and the others on Y ONLY and mybe some arguments in X AND Y

Comment: I can't figure out what you want.

Comment: file of args (-i -k -o -p -m) , i want x.py to have just -i -k -o to use when --help and Y.py just -o -p -m , Fixing the utilisation of args