# plugins pattern + sub command

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I will do a command line application with plugin capability, each new plugin will be invoked by a sub command from a `__main__.py` script.

I used to use `argparse`, I wonder if it's possible with `argparse` to implement sub command + plugin looking like (I found some tool but using deprecated packages) ?

```
myfantasticCLI
├── __main__.py
└── plugins
    ├── create.py
    ├── notify.py
    └── test.py
```

I know that I could use `argparse` for sub command, but don't know how to use it in a dynamic loading way. :/

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize the `argparse` subparsers with

```
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd',...)
```

then after parsing `args.cmd` will be the name of the chosen subparser or command.

Then a simple `if` tree could import and run the desired modules

```
cmd = args.cmd
if cmd in ['module1',...]:
   import plugins.module1 as mod:
   mod.run(...)
elif cmd in ['module2',....]:
   import plugins.module2 as mod:
   ...
```

There are fancier ways of doing this, but I prefer starting with the obvious.

Also my focus is on getting the `cmd` name from the parser, not on the details of importing a module given the name.  You don't need `argparse` to test the `import given a name` part of the problem.

Comment: Sounds great but, that implies explicit import. I would like to build something plugins based http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932069/building-a-minimal-plugin-architecture-in-python.

Comment: If all you need from `argparse` is the name of the plugin to import, the `subparsers` mechanism may be too much.  Any string argument would work.  You could even collect the allowable names in a `choices` parameter.